# How to check if a date of a booking is overlapping rails hotel application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a web application in Ruby on Rails for a hotel. I've seen some questions around that may look the same as mine, but I couldn't find the right solution.

A user can create a booking and choose which room they want and what day they are arriving and leaving. Everything is working as the way I want except of the fact that my rooms can be booked with overlapping dates.

**Schema**:

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user"
  t.integer  "course"
  t.date     "arriving_date"
  t.date     "leaving_date"
  t.boolean  "breakfast"
  t.text     "remarks"
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  t.integer  "room_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_room_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "room_number"
  t.integer  "room_type_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.index ["room_type_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_room_type_id", using: :btree
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong"
      render 'index'
    end
  end
```

**Model of booking**

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**What I want**

When a user tries to create a booking they should not be able to choose a certain room that is already booked at the days they want to sleep in the hotel.

Comment: want do you got so far? show your validation method

Comment: @Fallenhero I understand why you're asking that, but thing is that I completely have no clue how to make something like this..

Answer (score 2):

In roughest pseudo-code, I would extend Room with an instance method

```
# room.rb
def is_available? time_range
  bookings.present?(:arrival < time_range.end AND :depature > timerange.start)
end
```

Call this in your create action in the controller much like you do in your own answer.

You definately want to do this without looping over all your bookings!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try!

Comment: @StijnWesterhof Feel free to edit and give real code if it works (probably edit your own answer).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the given answers but I couldn't let that work yet. So I made my own solution but I'm not happy about it yet because of the "Fat model, skinny controller" thing.

This worked for me:

```
def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

  @date_start = @booking.arriving_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  @date_end = @booking.leaving_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  found = false
  @all_bookings = Booking.all
  @all_bookings.each do |booking|
    arival_date = booking.arriving_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    leave_date = booking.leaving_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    if @date_start.between?(arival_date, leave_date) || @date_end.between?(arival_date, leave_date)
      if booking.room_id == @booking.room_id
        found = true
      end
    end
  end

  if found == true
    redirect_to new_booking_path, notice: "This room is already booked in the period you want to book it"
  else
    @booking.save!
    redirect_to @booking
  end
end
```

I'm still interested in the 'right' answer :)

Comment: Do not loop over your bookings. You need to find a `ActiveRecord` or SQL solution. If you would have to, do not use `find`, use `find_each` instead (if ordering is not important). Also, early stop when you found the booking (your code will check ALL bookings, even if the first one overlaps!).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You will need something like (in your booking model):

```
validate(:validate_overlapping)

def validate_overlapping
  self.errors[:date] = "Overlapping booking" if Booking.where(#check_your_dates#).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Booking model,

```
before_create: check_date_availability

def self.check_date_availability(booking_params)
  bookings = Booking.where('arrival_date < ? OR leaving_date > ?', self.arrival_date, self.leaving_date)
  return bookings.empty?
end
```

Please change the condition in the query. AND or OR based on your requirement.

Comment: Shabihi, can't your function just return bookings.empty? 
There is no need for if/else/end.

Comment: yeah that is also fine. Thanks for the catch @ZaurAmikishiyev. Updated the answer.